# Wait until Jquery library has loaded before executing external javascript files

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to wait until the jquery library has loaded until we execute other external javascript files, so wait for this to completely load:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

then load other files such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="campaign_winter_2013/bg_outerwear/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="campaign_winter_2013/bg_outerwear/js/mousePosSlide.js"></script>
```

The problem being I am integrating code in a platform and the jquery library is loaded before my scripts.

Comment: you mean is loaded after?

Comment: you could get jquery to load int he scripts

Comment: usually it is enough to just embed the jquery script first then add others. is this your question?

Comment: use require.js it is good for that purpose http://requirejs.org/

Comment: It does that automagically all by itself unless you use async or defer. Maybe what you're really trying to do is wait for the DOM to be ready, and if so, that would be jQuery's document ready method ?

Answer (score 6):

You can load jquery library first and then invoke methods defined in your JS files. The following code worked for me.

```
<body> 

function loadJQuery(){

var waitForLoad = function () {
    if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
        console.log("jquery loaded..");
        // invoke any methods defined in your JS files to begin execution       
    } else {
        console.log("jquery not loaded..");
        window.setTimeout(waitForLoad, 500);
    }
 };
 window.setTimeout(waitForLoad, 500);   
}

window.onload = loadJQuery;

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/neohunter/ey2pqt5z/

It will create a fake jQuery object, that allows you to use the onload methods of jquery, and they will be executed as soon as jquery is loaded.

It's not perfect.

```js
// This have to be on <HEAD> preferibly inline
var delayed_jquery = [];
jQuery = function() {
  if (typeof arguments[0] == "function") {
    jQuery(document).ready(arguments[0]);
  } else {
    return {
      ready: function(fn) {
        console.log("registering function");
        delayed_jquery.push(fn);
      }
    }
  }
};
$ = jQuery;
var waitForLoad = function() {
  if (typeof jQuery.fn != "undefined") {
    console.log("jquery loaded!!!");
    for (k in delayed_jquery) {
      delayed_jquery[k]();
    }
  } else {
    console.log("jquery not loaded..");
    window.setTimeout(waitForLoad, 500);
  }
};
window.setTimeout(waitForLoad, 500);
// end



// now lets use jQuery (the fake version)
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert('Jquery now exists!');
});

jQuery(function() {
  alert('Jquery now exists, this is using an alternative call');
})

// And lets load the real jquery after 3 seconds..
window.setTimeout(function() {
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
  newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
  newscript.async = true;
  newscript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
}, 3000);
```